# JSP/servlet read parameters from properties file?

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

My JSP pages need to display different information depending on which environment they're in (dev, production, sandbox, etc).  I want to have a properties file for each of these environments that contain all the parameters they might need.  How can I reference the properties from this file in a JSP page?

My thoughts are:

- Have a servlet feed the properties in the form of a model object to all JSP pages so I can reference them like ${properties.propertyName}
- Somehow reference this property file in the web.xml, then maybe I call something like ${context.properties.propertyName}?
- Instead of a properties file, list parameters in web.xml and reference those in the JSP pages.  Not sure how to do this, but I'd very much prefer a simpler properties file.

***UPDATE*** - I should've mentioned I'm using Spring 3.0 and Spring webmvc.  So if there's some best practices way to do this using Spring, that's ideal!

Comment: spring would've come very handy here

Comment: I use Spring!!!  How does that help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You can load the properties using `java.util.Properties` (or [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)) in a `ServletContextListener`'s `contextInitialized(..)` method.
- register the listener with `<listener>` in web.xml
- You then store the `Properties` into the `ServletContext` (you can get it from the event) (`ctx.setAttribute("properties", properties)`
- then access the properties using `${applicationScope.properties.propName}` (as BalusC noted, `applicationScope` is optional)

**Update:**

Initially I thought spring had some ready-to-use facility for that, but it turns out it's not exactly the case. You have two options:

- [this article](http://j2eecookbook.blogspot.com/2007/07/accessing-properties-loaded-via-spring.html) explains something similar to my suggestion above, but using spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072101/accessing-spring-mvc-di-beans-from-jsp/2072285#2072285) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933862/how-to-use-property-from-property-file-specified-in-propertyplaceholderconfigurer) allow you to expose all your beans, including a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to the servlet context.

Comment: For the case it's not clear to the OP: the `applicationScope` part in EL is optional.

Comment: the 2 answers in your update was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the discussion of where is the best location to store environment-specific data (hint: certainly *not* property files), I would stick to the basics:

JSP pages render data; they don't fetch it. If at some point, later on, you end up getting properties from somewhere else other than a property file - your JSP, assuming your application is well-designed - should *not* change.

Therefore, the first approach you mentioned makes sense (assuming, again, that you'd like to stick with environment-specific information being read from Property files).

Comment: where do you suggest storing environment-specific data?

Comment: After spending months over months researching all alternatives - I reached the conclusion that using Resource Environment Entries is by far the most flexible approach. Your program will never change as part of environment shifts. Read more about resource environment entries and how to use them here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0611_totapally/0611_totapally.html - it talks WebSphere, but the concept of ResEnvEntries is J2EE-standard and every application server that I know of supports it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the properties file in a known location within your project.  For example: /WEB-INF/config/environment.properties.
2. Create a simple java bean class that has getters (accessors if you like) exposing each of the desired properties (I will refer to this as the PropertyExposer class).  For example: PropertyExposer.getEnvironmentName()
3. In a startup class (maybe a SessionContextListener or a servlet with a low <load-on-startup> value) load the properties, create your PropertyExposer object, and store it in session (or application based on your needs) scope.

After doing the above, your properties will be available to your JSP files.

If you initialize using a SessionContextListener (this is not valid code, but the point is made):

```
SessionContextListenser.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
{
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute();  // set application scope value.
}
```

If you initialize using a Servlet (assuming you extend GenericServlet):

```
YourServletClass.init()
{
    getServletContext().setAttribute(); // set application scope value.
}
```

Comment: How do I store and access the propertyExposer in application scope?  I like the idea, especially if I can poll the file periodically with my bean.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve it by exposing the config file in my webmvc-config.xml file using a Resource Bundle:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="classpath:META-INF/spring/config" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

Then I was able to use it in my JSPs using a <spring:message /> tag:

```
<spring:message code="reactor.appKey" var="reactorAppKey" />
<scrip data-app-key="${reactorAppKey}"></script>
```