# How to use property from property file specified in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

In my application context I have defined properties file:

```
<context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

I want to get value of the property defined in that file on JSP page. Is there a way to do that in the way

```
${something.myProperty}?
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can only parse placeholders in Spring configuration (XML or annotations). Is very common in Spring applications use a `Properties` bean. You can access it from your view this way (assuming you are using `InternalResourceViewResolver`):

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list><value>classpath:config.properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list><value>properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then, in your JSP, you can use `${properties.myProperty}` or `${properties['my.property']}`.

Comment: really good! But the first bean in declaration is of PropertiesFactoryBean type, not of ProperyPlaceholderConfigurer. Should this mean that in order to have replacement of property placeholders in xml I am to duplicate declaration of application properties in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerBean?

Comment: @glaz666: I forgot to say that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is not appropiate for this. I edited my answer a little.

Comment: I have passed this "properties" bean to PlaceHolderConfigurer and it seems to work, but still I can't make it work in JSP files because when I try to access ${properties} it is even not trying to call getAttribute from ContextExposingHttpServletRequest where bean exposing happens

Comment: @glaz666: Strange behaviour... Which version of Spring MVC are you using? ${...} works ok for other objects (such your controller results)?

Comment: Ok, I have figured out what is going on. I am using sitemesh and when I am trying to refer to a bean in spring context on decorator page it is unavailable due to no spring's request wrapper is applied at that time. I have created another question on how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952755/how-to-obtain-model-attribute-in-sitemesh-decorator. Thanks for help here!

Comment: is this possible with spring 2.0.x? I'm getting the following error on Tomcat startup : Invalid property 'exposedContextBeanNames' of bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver]: Bean property 'exposedContextBeanNames' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Properties implements Map, so you can use ${properties['i.want.chicken.now']}

Answer (score 6):

After Spring 3.1, you can use `<spring:eval />` tag with [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources) like this:

```
<spring:eval expression="@applicationProps['application.version']" 
             var="applicationVersion"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use with multiple locations in a list which might not be present as can be done with the context:property-placeholder bean:

```
<beans:bean id="appProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="locations">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>classpath:application.properties</beans:value>
            <beans:value>classpath:environment.properties</beans:value>
            <beans:value>classpath:environment-${env}.properties</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use recursive property placeholder expansion in views, you need a different solution, take a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200249/770303

Answer (score 0):

```
`<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" 
  id="messageSource"
  p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/site"
  p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>`
```

Now this is your **Properties File**

```
`site.name=Cool Bananas`
```

And.
Here goes your **JSP**

```
`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><spring:message code="site.name"/></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score -4):

This will show you the tables of the current schema (which you are logged in):

```
select table_name from user_tables order by table_name;
```

This will show you the tables of schema , for which you have select rights at least:

```
select owner, table_name from all_tables where owner='<owner>' order by owner, table_name;
```