# Linking endpoint in RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I have written an application that calls a service through Spring's RestTemplate. 
It's working fine when I call the URL `http://localhost:8081/index/myservice` directly. 
I tried configuring an endpoint using `application.properties`, how do I link it to the method calling the URL ? As it is now, It doesn't have any effect.

**application.properties**

```
 app.endpoint = http://localhost:8081/index/
```

I want to directly call `app.endpoint` instead of writing the URL.

**Update : ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


 <!-- Rest Template -->  

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">  
</bean>

<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
<property name="locations">
    <list><value>classpath:application.properties</value></list>
</property>
```

Comment: Have you tried using : ${app.endpoint} ? 
Check out the steps here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933862/how-to-use-property-from-property-file-specified-in-propertyplaceholderconfigure

Comment: do post here if that does not work out.

Comment: I've configured the ApplicationContext but I don't know how to call ${app.endpoint} ? if I put it just like that, it isn't reconized.

Comment: can you post the xml pls ? Please note, this is for use in the JSP. If your resttemplate is configured in the context xml, you can use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: That might be, I didn't copy the jsp part since I didn't use Jsp. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to call the URL from the method : You can use the @Value annotation like this :

`@Value("${app.endpoint}")
private String appEndpoint;`

The configuration in your XML :
`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:placeholder.properties"/>`

HTH,
Gyan