# What is the best way to create and use an initializaion file with parameters while doing a springmvc web project?

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc

I want to create a initilisation file in my spring-mvc web project . What is the best way to do it so that i will be able to get thoses value in my java files and as well in my jsp files ?
Thank you for any advise!

**UPDATE**

what if i wand to load thoses parameters from lets say an init.ini file and make them available all the time while the application is running?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make those parameters available to all jsp files and controllers you can create an interceptor.

```
public class ParametersInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


   Object parameters = null;
   public void loadParameters(){
      parameters = //Read from database or properties file.
   }

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

            request.setAttribute("parameters", parameters);
            return true;
    }

}
```

Then define your interceptor as a bean.

```
<bean name="parametersInterceptor"
    class="com.zzz.zzz.ParametersInterceptor"
    init-method="loadParameters" >
</bean>
```

Then in your urlMappping bean you can add this to tell spring that you want a list of interceptors to be executed for the defined mappings.

```
<property name="interceptors">
   <list>
    <ref bean="parametersInterceptor" />
   </list>
</property>
```

[Here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-interceptor.html) is an example using interceptors

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in that way, in each request ,i'll will have to do the same action, i may be loosing performance. what if i wand to load thoses parameters from lets say an init.ini file and make them available all the time while the application is running?

Comment: @stunaz You are right. I have updated my answer. Notice the init-method="loadParameters" and the new loadParameters method.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Spring webapps I work on have a properties file in src/main/resources that we access from both Java code as well as JSP files.

We use a custom taglib to load the property of interest like this:

```
<foo:propertyLoader bundle="bar" property="googleKey"/>
```

but there are many ways to read a properties file in JSP. See this stackoverflow question:

[JSP/servlet read parameters from properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920088/jsp-servlet-read-parameters-from-properties-file/3920123#3920123)

We tend to store things like GoogleAPI keys, Google Analytic key, URIs to other web applications, etc in there.