# Creating custom shortcodes for my website

Tags: php

Good day everyone, i am currently working on a php project and i want to be able to create short codes similar to that of wordpress.

```
Example: [welcome title="Welcome to our website" img="../example.jpg"]
         the welcome message here
         [/welcome]
```

result should be well formatted in a div element.
Thank you.

Comment: try using a properties file

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686465/how-to-use-property-file-in-jsp

Comment: @ScaryWombat that is not what the OP is asking at all.

Comment: Have you considered using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)? It's the same syntax used at StackExchange for all their sites (including [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: I'm confused as to what language this is in.... VTC

Comment: @ScaryWombat just read my comment above James Massey's.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Sorry as the OP tagged this Q with java and mentions HTML I assumed he was using jsp - my bad.

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3b6c9519a8f83a3fd834bc047899b49547e9d592/wp-includes/shortcodes.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the Just Variables plugin for Wordpress.

You can store variables in the Admin and use them in your content (Posts and Pages) like this:

```
[justvars code="welcome-title"]
```

Or direct in your PHP code like this:

```
<?php just_variable("welcome-title"); ?>
```

Simple instructions and works really well!

Or, something that may be better suited to your question, is by simply creating a function.

```
 function welcome_message () {
     $welcome_message = "<div>This is your string</div>";
     return $welcome_message;
 }
```

And then you can call that function in your code by a simple echo statement:

```
<?php echo welcome_message(); ?>
```