# Use properties from a file outside WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a file named '*message.properties*' placed on /src/main/resources and it works fine when I try to access its data on any .jsp file inside the /WEB-INF folder.

The thing is: I have a file (404.jsp) placed **outside** the /WEB-INF folder and I want to use the keys stored inside message.properties, but it cannot find them, giving me errors like "`??? key.myKey ???`

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

How can I access the properties file **from** a file outside the /WEB-INF folder? I've tried changing the base name to "../resoruces/" or something like this, but couldn't solve the problem.

Again: it works fine for every file inside the WEB-INF folder, the issue is only with 404.jsp

**Edit:** I cannot solve it adding a scriptlet, because inside my 404.jsp I have some includes that need the same keys from message.properties

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686465/how-to-use-property-file-in-jsp

Comment: The pages in the WEB-INF folder are served from the `DispatcherServlet` the 404 knows nothing about such a thing and hence nothing about the spring based enhancements. Why don't you just move the 404 into the WEB-INF and let the `DispatcherServlet` handle it?

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, I think the standard is to leave 404.jsp outside WEB-INF folder, since every time Spring fails to map a page it will fallback to 404.jsp... Is there any implication if I put it inside WEB-INF folder?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file for properties

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/your_path/test_properties.txt");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(fis);
```

Comment: Well, how would I access it in my 404.jsp file? If possible, I would like a solution that doesn't need a java snippet

Comment: @GabrielR. sorry, it's java, you put it between < % and % > and with the import

Comment: Got it, but is there another way to do it? I would like to avoid java snippets on my .jsp files :)

Comment: Yet, there is another problem... in my 404.jsp file I include some jsp files from WEB-INF folder and they wouldn't be able to load the keys from the properties @guillaume girod-vitouchkina