# How to avoid hardcoding strings in web app

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp+servlet web application, which runs on tomcat server. All the strings which i use are hardcoded now. If possible I want to move all the hardcoded strings to one resource file and point to particular string in jsp code. How can i do it. Is there any other way other than resource file.For example: In below switch statement, i want to remove all hardcoded strings in case statement and move to one resource file or so and point to that string in my code.

```
switch (request.getParameter("mode")) {
                case "check1": {

                    break;
                }
                case "check2": {

                    break;
                }
                case "active_inactive": {

                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: show an example of what you're doing currently. Post some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use property file in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686465/how-to-use-property-file-in-jsp)

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte I have edited code with example

Comment: you could create a class where you can store those strings, then just refer to the class whenever you want to use a string from it...

Comment: example: `case Globals.CHECK_2: {`

Comment: @Jonathan Laliberte Thats one way, but is there any way that i can copy all strings to an xml or any other resource file and point to it

Comment: @Vinod yeah try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380156/java-properties-properties-files-vs-xml

Answer (score 2):

Use class named Constants for this pupose.

```
 public class Constants{

   public static String CHECK_1 = "Check1";
   public static String CHECK_2 = "Check2";


 }
```

And use this in anywhere you want.

```
      switch (request.getParameter("mode")) {
            case Constants.CHECK_1: {

                break;
            }
            case Constants.CHECK_2: {

                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thats one way, but is there any way that i can copy all strings to an xml or any other resource file and point to it

Comment: I'm sure that's possible. Though I do not know the exact reason for your requirement , I would not recommend such approach to  store constants as it would cost you performance and  management issues

Comment: @Vinod You can only use constants or literals in a switch, so if you want to get those strings from a resource file, you'll need to switch to another solution (eg using a map).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel That was just an example. I have strings which i want to move to resource file such as xml. This is my primary concern.

Comment: @Vinod Then you shouldn't be asking about about your actual problem and not the switch construct, because there strings can't be externalized.