# Get value from xml properties file in Java and using on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, properties

I have a properties xml file, example:

```
<properties>
  <entry key="message.first">Hello</entry>
  <entry key="message.second">Hi</entry>
</properties>
```

and I want get the value from properties file and check if value is exist on the jsp page.

Example:

```
if(message.first != null) {
     action
}
```

I don't now how get value from properties file and use in if statment on jsp page.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140653/how-to-load-a-properties-file-into-a-jsp

Comment: @MickMnemonic Sorry, my mistake this is xml properties file.

Comment: I think you can still use the advice in the dupe, using [`loadFromXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream)) for loading the data.

Answer (score 3):

**For Loading properties.xml File :-**

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.loadFromXML(new FileInputStream("props.xml")); //path of XML file
    String  firstname = properties.getProperty("firstname");
```

**For Sending it to JSP Page** :-

```
    request.setAttribute("firstname ", firstname )
    request.getRequestDispatcher("NEWPAGE.jsp").forward(request, response);
```